# WCF RIA Services, Custom Role Provider, using in Domain Service and UserBase

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services, roleprovider

I've created my own role provider in a SL4/RIA Services application, and I have had success using the [RequiresRole] attribute on a Domain Service call.  I can set a breakpoint in GetRolesForUser and see that it works.

This leads me to some other questions:

How and/or where do I use the other overridden methods in the custom provider?  Is it possible to use them within domain service calls?  If so is it simply a matter of creating a new instance of the RoleProvider, calling the methods on it, etc.?

Within the custom role provider, is it possible to make domain service calls?  If so, same thing, do I simply create/use a new instance of the entities ObjectContext?

Can the AuthenticatedUser instance be hooked into the role provider somehow?  I see it has a .Roles property and an .IsInRole method, but can that class be extended somehow to hook into the custom provider?

Any direction on these questions is greatly appreciated.